# Optimizing UICollectionViewCell content loading

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with a densely populated grid of cells. Approximately 50 views are reloaded every time the user scrolls a fraction of the screen height.

It's buttery smooth on all iPhones down to the 5. On the 5, it's slightly choppy - not horrible, but more than I'd like.

I've tested by completely detaching my data structure (a simple nested dictionary), and the framerate is the same, so that's not the issue.

Is there any further optimization I can do, or is this simply a limitation of the device?

Simplified code is below:

```
class dayCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        for index in 0..<subviewCount {
            createView(contentView)
        }
    }
}

func createView(view: UIView) {
    let myView = UIView()
    // ...
    view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

Comment: That's not the relevant code. The relevant code is what is executed when cells are reused and populated. You should also use the instruments time profiler which will tell you exactly where the slow code is.

Comment: And another relevant question is how the cells do layout when you populate them with new data. If they use Auto Layout, that's slower than manual layout. If they modify their view hierarchy, that's expensive. If the view hierarchy is deep or complex, that in itself might be expensive, versus flattening it into a bitmap.

Comment: I've come across to a similar issue when I've been using custom font and I forgot to state them in info.plist file.

Comment: @algal The view hierarchy is shallow - simply a single generation of children, and it's the same hierarchy in every cell. And I don't use Auto Layout.

Comment: @jrturton I'm not sure I understand. The speed issue doesn't seem dependent on the cell reuse code, because even if I comment out the contents of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, so the cells simply appear as subclassed above, the lagginess remains. Can you clarify? I'll look into the time profiler though, thanks.

Comment: I meant that the initialisation code for your cells is irrelevant. It isn't repeatedly called when you are scrolling, and that's when your lagging occurs. If that's the case then your first suspect is the cellForItem..., if you've eliminated that, probably something wrong in a custom layout ... but the time profiler will tell you for sure.